# o.s.w.s.s.support.KeyStoreFactoryBean : Creating empty key store

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-ws

i am trying to inport keystore (jks). I have file in right dir but still I do not know why I am getting error like:

```
o.s.w.s.s.support.KeyStoreFactoryBean    : Creating empty key store
o.s.w.s.s.support.KeyStoreFactoryBean    : Creating empty key store
```

I path is 100% sure right as I am loading also policy config via same method."ClassPathResource"

```
    KeyStoreFactoryBean keyStoreFactoryBean = new KeyStoreFactoryBean();
    keyStoreFactoryBean.setPassword("secret");

    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("test.jks");
    File file = resource.getFile();
    System.out.println("asdasa: "+file.toString());

    keyStoreFactoryBean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("test.jks"));

    keyStoreFactoryBean.setType("JKS");
    keyStoreFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
```

Log from syslog is ok: asdasa: C:\Users\miha_\OneDrive\Dokumenti\Job\Lj\Spring\Porting\target\classes\test.jks

in this dir the keystore is located. I tried with creating new keystore and it is the same. I opened it with keystore expolere and private/public key par is in there.

tnx